# Aumentar el valor de una columna de un archivo .csv usando php

Tags: php, csv, file

Busco alguna explicación  o ayuda de como resolver este problema :

```
$s ='1245';

$f = fopen(__DIR__ .'/datos/saved.csv', 'r');
$result = false;
while ($row = fgetcsv($f, 0, ',')) {
     if ($row[0] == $s) {
        $result = $row[2];
         $a = fopen(__DIR__ .'/datos/saved.csv', 'a');
         fputcsv($a, $result+1);
         fclose($a);
         break;
        }else{
        $result = 'url no existe';

            }
}
 fclose($f);
}
```

Como pueden notar busco la manera de ir aumentando el valor de la columna 2 del csv.

Si encuentra un resultado igual a la variable **$s**.

Aun no se por que no funciona espero alguna ayuda . gracias

Comment: El parámetro 'a' del fopen es para agregar datos al final del archivo, ademas de que quieres escribir en un archivo que ya tienes abierto, te recomiendo que por un lado leas el csv y por otro lo reescribas con otro nombre y al final renombres el seguno con el nombre original. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta e usado 'w' en lugar de 'a' y borra todas las columnas  me pregunto si me das algún ejemplo  para entender mejor  .